# Using Spring Data JPA with QueryDsl, paginated queries break sorting

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Given the following query, my results are sorted by the order number in descending order.  While attempting to return paginated results, the sorting seems to break.  I've tried it without the .orderBy() expression and adding a QSort instance to my QPageRequest.  I've tried calling the applySorting() method directly and passing a QSort, but for all intensive purposes, the pagination call breaks any kind of sorting I try.

I'm using QueryDsl 3.3.4 and Spring Data JPA 1.6.4. as imported by the Spring IO BOM 1.0.3.

```
public List<Object[]> findAll(PersonProfile personProfile) {
    QOrderStop shipper = new QOrderStop("shipper");
    QOrderStop consignee = new QOrderStop("consignee");
    JPQLQuery query = this.from(order)
            .leftJoin(order.orderStops, shipper).on(shipper.originalStopSequence.eq(BigDecimal.valueOf(1)))
            .leftJoin(order.orderStops, consignee).on(consignee.originalStopSequence.intValue().eq(order.orderStops.size()))
            .where(order.company.eq(company).and(OrderExpressions.customerCodePredicate(order, personProfile)))
            .orderBy(order.number.desc());

    //this.getQuerydsl().applyPagination(new QPageRequest(0, 10), query);

    return query
            .list(
                    order.number, order.status, order.shipperReferenceNumber, order.consigneeReferenceNumber,
                    order.shipperCustomer.billingCity, order.shipperCustomer.state,
                    shipper.latestScheduleDate, shipper.latestScheduleTime,
                    order.consigneeCustomer.billingCity, order.consigneeCustomer.state,
                    consignee.latestScheduleDate, consignee.latestScheduleTime
            ).stream()
            .map(Tuple::toArray)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

**EDIT - Using .limit(20) for pagination instead of .applyPagination()**

query.toString() before query.limit(20)

```
select order1
from Order order1
  left join order1.orderStops as shipper on shipper.originalStopSequence = ?1
  left join order1.orderStops as consignee on cast(consignee.originalStopSequence integer) = size(order1.orderStops)
where order1.company = ?2 and (order1.customer = ?3 or order1.billTo in ?4 or order1.shipper in ?5 or order1.consignee in ?5)
order by order1.number desc
```

query.toString() after query.limit(20) - no change

```
select order1
from Order order1
  left join order1.orderStops as shipper on shipper.originalStopSequence = ?1
  left join order1.orderStops as consignee on cast(consignee.originalStopSequence integer) = size(order1.orderStops)
where order1.company = ?2 and (order1.customer = ?3 or order1.billTo in ?4 or order1.shipper in ?5 or order1.consignee in ?5)
order by order1.number desc
```

Final query output by EclipseLink

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT EL_TEMP.*, ROWNUMBER() OVER() AS EL_ROWNM FROM (SELECT t0.OHOR# AS a1, t0.OHORST AS a2, t0.OHSRF# AS a3, t0.OHCRF# AS a4, t1.CUBCTY AS a5, t1.CUBST AS a6, t2.BSLSDT AS a7, t2.BSLSTM AS a8, t3.CUBCTY AS a9, t3.CUBST AS a10, t4.BSLSDT AS a11, t4.BSLSTM AS a12 FROM LIB.DPORDHP t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN LIB.DPORDSP t2 ON (((t2.BSOR# = t0.OHOR#) AND ((t2.BSOL# = t0.OHORS#) AND (t2.BSCM = t0.OHCM))) AND (t2.BSRSQS = ?)) LEFT OUTER JOIN LIB.DPORDSP t4 ON (((t4.BSOR# = t0.OHOR#) AND ((t4.BSOL# = t0.OHORS#) AND (t4.BSCM = t0.OHCM))) AND (CAST(t4.BSRSQS AS integer) = (SELECT COUNT(t5.BSOR#) FROM LIB.DPORDSP t5 WHERE ((t5.BSOR# = t0.OHOR#) AND ((t5.BSOL# = t0.OHORS#) AND (t5.BSCM = t0.OHCM)))))), LIB.SWCUSTP t3, LIB.SWCUSTP t1 WHERE (((t0.OHCM = ?) AND ((((t0.OHCUST = ?) OR (t0.OHBID IN (?,?))) OR (t0.OHSID IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))) OR (t0.OHCID IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)))) AND (((t1.CUCID = t0.OHSID) AND (t1.CUCM = t0.OHCM)) AND ((t3.CUCID = t0.OHCID) AND (t3.CUCM = t0.OHCM)))) ORDER BY t0.OHOR# DESC) AS EL_TEMP) AS EL_TEMP2 WHERE EL_ROWNM <= ?) AS EL_TEMP3 WHERE EL_ROWNM > ?
```

Comment: How does query.toString() look like after your applyPagination call? And how before?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how applyPagination breaks the ordering, but it might be more intuitive to use query.limit and query.offset here, since you are inside a repository method.

```
...
.orderBy(order.number.desc()).
.limit(pageSize)
.offset((page-1) * pageSize);
```

Comment: I haven't tried that.  Since I'm new to QueryDsl and my background is more with Spring Data JPA, I was trying the Spring Data approach to pagination and sorting.  I'll give it a try and see if it works better :)

Comment: I tried using .limit(20), but the sorting still seems to break.  I've confirmed this by removing the .limit(20) and the sorting then works.  Not sure what the issue is.  I've edited my original post with some more details.

Comment: Looks like an issue with EclipseLink, Querydsl renders the order by correctly, the limit part is not rendered in JPQL, but set on the JPA query.